# ImageView size is not displayed correctly

Tags: android, gridview, bitmap, imageview, android-gridview

I'm having a problem of displaying ImageViews with the correct size. Almost all the posts that I've read through involves ImageViews that are created in the layout file. However in my case, I'm creating ImageViews programmatically.

I'm trying to display all images from a particular folder located in the storage. The bitmaps retrieved will be placed in ImageViews which are contained within a GridView.

Here's my code:

```
//pass an array containing all images paths to adapter
imageGrid.setAdapter(new GridViewAdapter(getActivity(), FilePathStrings));
```

part of GridVewAdapter code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;

            if(convertView == null){
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

            }else{
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            imageView.setTag(filepath[position]);
            new LoadImages(imageView).execute();

            return imageView;
        }
```

AsyncTask to retrieve bitmaps:

```
private class LoadImages extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Bitmap> {

        private ImageView imgView;
        private String path;

        private LoadImages(ImageView imgView) {
            this.imgView = imgView;
            this.path = imgView.getTag().toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;

            BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bmOptions.inSampleSize = 6;

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, bmOptions);
            try {

                int dimension = getSquareCropDimensionForBitmap(bitmap);
                bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bitmap, dimension, dimension);

            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return bitmap;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

            if (!imgView.getTag().toString().equals(path)) {
                return;
            }

            if(result != null && imgView != null){
                imgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imgView.setImageBitmap(result);

            }else{
                imgView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
```

Method to get equal dimensions so bitmaps will be displayed as squares:

```
private int getSquareCropDimensionForBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {

           int dimension;
            //If the bitmap is wider than it is height then use the height as the square crop dimension

            if (bitmap.getWidth() >= bitmap.getHeight())    {
                dimension = bitmap.getHeight();
            }
            //If the bitmap is taller than it is width use the width as the square crop dimension

           else    {
                dimension = bitmap.getWidth();
            }
            return dimension;

    }
```

GridView in the layout file:

```
    <GridView
    android:id="@+id/imageGridView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnWidth="30dp"
    android:numColumns="5"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

</GridView>
```

The result that I've gotten:

[image: imgview_result]

The circled thin "lines" are actually the ImageViews displayed.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to set `layout_height` to `"match_parent"`?

Comment: I can't do that as there are other views above the GridView but I've found the solution. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have other views above the GridView so I can't set its height to fill_parent/match_parent in the .xml file as it will affect the views above.

The solution to my problem is to set GridView's height and width programmatically.

Replace:

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

With this:

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(int height, int width));
```

Explanation:

[Grid View doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

**Anyone who has a better answer, please post it** :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<GridView
android:id="@+id/imageGridView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp">
```

Comment: There are other views above the GridView, hence I won't be able to set the height to fill_parent. I resorted to setting the height and width of the GridView programmatically and it works. Thank you for your help :)